# Is it a good idea to set visibility to 'Catalog' only for configurable 'SIMPLE/associated' products?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, google-product-feeds

Our Magento store is having some issues with Google Merchant center.

Google requires us to have landing pages for all associated products in order to run adwords campaign. The problem is, by default, only configurable products are displayed in `catalog and search` whereas the simple products are `not displayed individually`. 
One solution to fix this issue is to set simple product visibility to catalog only so they are only accessible via direct link.

My question is, would it break anything in Magento or cause us issues if we set simple products to display in catalog only?

I hope I haven't confused anyone here.

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 1):

for my knowledge There will be no problem, if customers enter `direct url` of simple products, than only they can buy the simple[associated] products. if it is okay for you, than you can set simple products for "`catalog`"